# mod_dnssd not loading fedora 23

Tags: apache, fedora-23

Installing PackStack on Fedora 23.
Getting an issue with httpd not starting
in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/ there is a file 10-mod_dnssd
in /etc/httpd/conf.d there is a file mod_dnssd.conf

Apache fails to start with error message about invalid option: "DNSSDEnable on"
in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_dnssd.conf

I've checked with httpd -M and it looks like the module is not being loaded. However the LoadModule command looks file as per other examples around and the DNSSDEnable option looks to be valid as well.

I've not seen this issue anywhere on google, so before I raise a bug report i wanted to see if anyone else had encountered it or had a fix.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I moved the LoadModule statement elsewhere and got the module to load. I haven't gone back to look at why it wasn't loading.

Comment: To be honest haven't had a chance to look at it again. I'll maybe try this weekend

Comment: Where did you move it to?

Comment: Haven't looked at this in awhile, but IIRC I just moved it into the main module config file. Wherever the majority of the modules were being loaded...

Comment: I just commented it out. Doesnt seem to be needed for packstack

Answer (score 0):

```
# apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_dnssd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_dnssd.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dnssd.so: undefined symbol: unixd_setup_child
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_dnssd.conf
LoadModule dnssd_module modules/mod_dnssd.so

DNSSDEnable on
#DNSSDAutoRegisterVHosts on
#DNSSDAutoRegisterUserDir on

#  ls -l /etc/httpd/conf.d/modules
ls: cannot access /etc/httpd/conf.d/modules: No such file or directory

ls -l /etc/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Mar  4 22:09 /etc/httpd/modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
```

So I changed the first line of mod_dnssd.conf to an absolute path like this:

> LoadModule dnssd_module /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dnssd.so

... but sadly I came across yet another error as such:-

```
# apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_dnssd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dnssd.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dnssd.so: undefined symbol: unixd_setup_child
```

so I had to uninstall the dnssd module altogether with this command:

```
# yum remove mod_dnssd
```

That's on RHEL 7 running Apache 2.4.6  but I assume it holds true for Fedora as well

Answer (score 0):

P.S. Red Hat states that:-

"The following packages have been removed from Red Hat Enterprise Linux between version 6 and version 7 and are no longer supported.
...
mod_dnssd
..."

Source [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Migration Planning Guide -  Removed Packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Migration_Planning_Guide-Removed_Packages.html)